# Iterate/Traverse JSON Object AngularJS and put into new JSON Obj

Tags: angularjs

So I am new to AngularJS and I am trying to figure out a way to iterate over a JSON object and pick out each value I need. I know I need to use a forEach loop to go through but I am having trouble reaching each value in the object, and then putting them into a new object.

**json**

```
var values =
{
      "profile": {
        "fields": {
          "number-of-fields": "700",
          "interpertation": [
            "whenever this is ready"
          ],
          "type": "test",
          "values": "450"
        }
      },
      "id": "12312312333645"
    }
```

**angular**

```
$scope.newObj={}:

     angular.forEach(info, function (value, key) {
                console.log(key, ":", value);
                    //add to object 



                angular.forEach(value, function (value, key) {
                    console.log(key, ":", value);
                     //


                    angular.forEach(value, function (value, key) {
                        console.log(key, ":", value);


                    })
                })
            })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ygahqdge/188/

Aslo for some reason the last item is repeating itself

Comment: whats the reason you want it in a new object? you dont want it nested? if thats the case, then why not use angular $filter?

Comment: Not clear at all what objective is or use case or expected results

Comment: i want to skim a large json object pick out what I want and put those items into a new JSON OBject

Comment: Check out `angular.copy` as a way to do a deep copy of objects from within the JSON. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy